# Analyzing only modified classes in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to know if it's possible to focus a sonar analysis in the classes you have modified.

Imagine you have a huge project, analyzed with a SonarQube Ant Task that can spend a lot of time analyzing all its code and generating the results in the server.
If you only modified 3 classes in this huge project... would be possible to make a shorter analysis with only that 3 classes and update the results?
I'm looking the 'sonar.sources' and 'sonar.exclusions' properties, but I cant find a solution.

My idea is to have the complete proyect analyzed in sonar server. If you use the Sonar Eclipse Plugin you can see all the info displayed, and if you use the sonar ant task you can update the information, but only analyzing the source you have modified.

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be implemented in next version of SonarQube (4.0).

You can vote and watch the following ticket: [SONAR-3677](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3677)